# Dropout for LSTMs

Tags: lstm, dropout

I've been just told that using Dropout For LSTMs is not considered the right thing these days. Is it true? If yes, what is recommended for overfitting prevention with LSTMs?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is dropout not correct? Can you provide additional information?

Answer (score 1):

I think the people you are speaking to referring to how dropout is used in regularizing LSTMs. See section 3.2 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2329.pdf where the authors state "The dropout operator corrupts the information carried by the units,
forcing them to perform their intermediate computationsmore robustly. At the same time, we do not
want to erase all the information from the units". Is this what you are referring to?